# Unable to get KeyEvent Stop from bluetooth headset(PTT) device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am using MediaButton action filter for receiving Bluetooth headset media button events. The Action filter was working android lollipop and below versions but not working in android M and above.

In those mentioned devices only `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:` is working.

List of Actions performed.
1. Click PTT(Push To Talk) Button
    - Got callback in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` with event `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:`
2. Release PTT Button
    - Should get callback in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` with event `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:` - But didn't receive this event only in the above mentioned devices.

I have mentioned the code that I used below.

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pttsample">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".MediaButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Receiver**

```
public class MediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON))
    {

        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null)
            return;

        if (event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
                && event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
                && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return;
        }

        Intent i = null;

                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","Power Button Play app destroy");
        switch (event.getKeyCode())
        {
           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","Power Button Play KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","Power Button Play MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE");
                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (event.getRepeatCount() > 0)
                            break;

                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // long click
                        Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","Power Button Play Action Up");
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE:
                        Log.e("MEDIA", "Action Multiple");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            //The following is the received from PTT device button
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                 Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER>>>","Button Play");
                 break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","Power Button Pause");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_AUDIO_TRACK:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","audio track");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_CLOSE:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","close");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_EJECT:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","eject");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","fast forward");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","next");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","previous");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_RECORD:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","record");
                break;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","rewind");
                break;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                Log.e("MEDIA CONTROLLER","stop");
                break;
        }

        if (isOrderedBroadcast())
            abortBroadcast();
        if (i != null)
            context.sendBroadcast(i);
    }


}
```

**MainActivity**

Already tried by adding the following.

```
    mMediaControlClientReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(
            getPackageName(), MediaButtonReceiver.class.getName());
    mMediaStopReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(
            getPackageName(), MediaButtonReceiver.class.getName());

    audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManagerStopOption = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mMediaControlClientReceiverComponent);
    audioManagerStopOption.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mMediaStopReceiverComponent);
```

Comment: Did you found solution yet . post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same problem.
I do not know if this is Android wide, but is is happening on my Samsung S6 that I use to develop.

First of all, even without a MediaSession, when you're UI is the active one (so visible on the screen), this is also happening. When the UI is active, the media keys are send to the activity.

Here is how I solved the problem.

You need to set the Audiomanager to MODE_NORMAL

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

At this point, even whithout setting the audio focus, you will receive the MEDIA_PLAY triggered by pushing the mic PTT.
You can capture this with the keyDown triggered in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean(int keyCode KeyEvent event){
    if (keyCode == 126) startPlay();
    return true;
}
```

Then you can for example start playing something with the MediaPlayer class.
It is only when actually playing something that the MEDIA_STOP and other keys will be send to your application.

However I think you are creating some sort of Walky Talky app. And you will be streaming RTP. I myself do this with the AudioTrack class. And when starting the audiotrack with play(), also makes the other media keys available.

As you probably want to use the microphone from the PTT MIC, you will have to connect using Bluetooth sco. This is also done through the AudioManager. Something like this

```
  audio.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
  audio.stopBluetoothSco();
```

However this breaks all of the above and only MEDIA_PLAY is received.
Up till now I have found only one solution, and that is to use a Bluetooth socket. Below is the class I use. It is especially for the Dellking PTT Mic

```
package on4akh.be.remotehamming;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothPtt {
    private  byte[] mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
    private InputStream in;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private OnMessageReceived pttState = null;

    public BluetoothPtt(OnMessageReceived listener){
        pttState = listener;
        Set<BluetoothDevice> bs = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : bs){
            if (device.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("DellKing PTT Mic")){
                try{
                    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                    start();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    return;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    private void start(){
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    socket.connect();
                    in = socket.getInputStream();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    socket = null;
                    return;
                }

                while (isRunning){
                    try {
                        if (socket.isConnected()){
                            in.read(mmBuffer);
                            if (mmBuffer[5] == 80){
                                pttState.isPressed(true);
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    pttState.isPressed(false);
                                }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void release(){
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){

        }
        socket = null;
    }

    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void isPressed(boolean state);
    }
}
```

Every time you press and release the PTT button, a 6 byte code is send, where the sixth byte is 80 for press and 82 for release.
The class has an onMessagedReceived listener that I use to toggle the PTT in my application

```
  BluetoothPtt  ptt = new BluetoothPtt(new BluetoothPtt.OnMessageReceived(){
            @Override
            public void isPressed(boolean state){
                togglePtt();
            }
        });
```

Hopefully you can use my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to achievie button clicks on popular Xiaomi Mi Headset (vol up and down). Device has 6 UUIDs, I can collect `InputStream` only from one, it hangs on `in.read(buffer)` (not reading, not throwing an exception). Audio works fine. Any suggestions please?